# Proof or disprove that the following statement is true

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a problem I need help with:

Prove or disprove that *P*(*M* $\cup$ *N*) $\neq$ *P*(*M*) $\cup$ P(*N*).

**What I have tried so  far**

**Consider:** *M* = $\{ a,b,c\}$ *and* *N* = $\{\text{red},\text{blue},\text{yellow}\}$

$\Rightarrow$ *P*(*M*) ${}= 3^3 = 27$ *and* *P*(*N*) ${} = 3^3$

**Combine *P*(*M*)$\cup$*P*(*N*)**

$\Rightarrow \bigcup \{M,N\} = \{x\mid(x\in M) \text{ and } (x\in N)\}$

$\Rightarrow$ *P*(*M* ${}\cup{}$ *N*) ${}= \{a,b,c,\text{red}, \text{blue}, \text{yellow} \}$

$\Rightarrow$ *P*(*M,N*) ${}= 6^6 = 46656$

$\Rightarrow$ *P*(*M* $\cup$ *N*) ${}\neq{}$ *P*(*M*) ${}\cup{}$ P(*N*)

**Is my answer correct?**

Comment: No.${}{}{{}}{}$

Comment: The question itself is ill-posed, since $M$ and $N$ are unquantified. There are sets $M$ and $N$ for which $\mathcal{P}(M \cup N) \ne \mathcal{P}(M) \cup \mathcal{P}(N)$ is true, and sets for which it is false.

Comment: In a question, for all unquantified variables, you can assume there is a $\forall$ quantifier in front of the question - this implicit $\forall$ is quite common in mathematical language.

Comment: Sometimes (often) I'm amazed at how people posting answers manage to make things more complicated than they are. I've posted an answer that I how makes the matter appear as simple as it really is.

Comment: Has anyone besides me up-voted the question? One might think people posting answers would do that.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer has a good idea but there are some technical mistakes in it.

For example, you say $P(M)=3^3$, which is **not** true.

- First of all, $P(M)$ is a **set**, while $3^3$ is a number. The two are not equal.
- What you probably want to say $|P(M)|=3^3$, i.e. that the size of the set $P(M)$ is $3^3$. But even then, no, that is not true.

---

To try the proof again, I suggest you try to construct a smaller counterexample, and ditch the idea of set sizes. Simply look at the power sets directly.

---

For an added challenge, try proving this statement:

> $P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)$ if and only if $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}.$

Then $\{2,3,a,b\}$ is a member of $P(A\cup B)$ but is not a member of $P(A)\cup P(B).$

Comment: While I agree that this is a simple answer, I don't think this answers the question posed by the OP. The OP is asking "Is my answer correct?", and this answer tells him nothing about that. OP made a pretty big mistake in his reasoning, and I think telling him about that mistake should be a big part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take $M$ and $N$ to be any two disjoint nonempty finite sets of cardinality $m$ and $n$ respectively. Then $|P(M \cup N)|=2^{m+n}$. $P(M) \cap P(N)=\{ \{ \} \}$, so $$|P(M) \cup P(N)|=|P(M)|+|P(N)|-1=2^m + 2^n -1,$$
and since this number is odd, it can never be true that $P(M \cup N)=P(M) \cup P(N)$.